# Serpent Расшифрование

Tags: криптография

Здравствуйте!

При процессе расшифрования InvSbox идут в обратном порядке, то есть от S7 до S0? Если на 31 раунде вместо применения линейной трансформации мы накладывали ключ K31{k124,k125,126,127} и K32{k128,k129,k130,k131}, то тогда обратная операция в расшифрование наложение ключа происходит на 0 раунде (i=0) S7(x0,x1,x2,x3 xor k128,129,k130,k131) xor (k124,k125,k126,k127), и дальше цикл расшифрования начинается от 1 до 31 (i=0;i<32;i++)? И нужно ли заново проводит IP/FP? Т.к. в процессе шифрования до раундов проводилась IP, затем при получение шифрованного текста проводилась FP. То теперь перед раундами расшифрования, нужно опять проводить IP, а после последнего раунда FP, для получения исходного текста? Заранее спасибо!

Значит, цикл шифрования начинается с 1 до 31 (i=1;i<32;i++)?
В 0 (первом раунде) пропускаем обратное линейное преобразование и накладываем дополнительный ключ i=0, S7(B0 xor K32) xor K31? Только непонятно, нужно ли проводить IP/FP замены?

Comment: @Rrace8 вы не отвечаете на ответы, не комментируете, никак не откликаетесь - вам неинтересно отвечать.

Comment: Почему, в этом вопросе Я полностью расписал итерации раундовых ключей http://hashcode.ru/questions/367302/%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-serpent-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8 ,но никто не ответил, правильно ли я рассчитал ключи.А если ключи неправильные, то смысла в этом шифрование не будет, так как не получиться расшифровать текст.